# How to convert chromium os bin file from Source Forge to iso?

Tags: virtualbox, iso, file-types

I want to convert the bin file from [source forge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chromiumosx64/?source=directory) I've try to call:

```
bchunk chromiumos_image.bin chromiumos_image.cue chromiumos_image.iso
```

but got error:

```
Could not open BIN chromiumos_image.bin: Value too large for defined data type
```

I also tried:

```
iat chromiumos_image.bin chromiumos_image.iso
```

but got error:

```
Image is broken
This image is not CD IMAGE
```

the file command say it's:

```
chromiumos_image.bin: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, 
start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x3ff,255,63), startsector 1, 5058495 sectors
```

how can I convert it to iso so I can run it in VirtualBox?

Comment: It's working fine here with `bchunk`. I have downloaded the **.xz** file. What *cue* file are you using ?

Comment: @solsTiCe I'm using **.bin** file from **.gz** file, will download **.xz**

Comment: @solsTiCe how do you execute the command? I'm also not able to convert .xz file to iso.

Comment: You need to decompress the *.xz* file like the *.gz*

Comment: @solsTiCe yes I unpacked it and the content is the same as in ***.gz*** file.

Answer (score 2):

You create a chromiumos_image.cue file with the content:

```
FILE ”chromiumos_image.bin” BINARY
TRACK 01 MODE1/2352
INDEX 01 00:00:00
```

and you run

```
bchunk chromiumos_image.bin chromiumos_image.cue chromiumos_image.iso
```

Comment: I've got error `Could not open BIN chromiumos_image.bin: Value too large for defined data type`. I'm using 32bit Xubuntu 16.04.